# curl retry after transfer operation timeout

Tags: c, timeout, libcurl

I have wrote a code that will download file with multiple curl handles in parallel from server in multipart and then it will merge the downloaded file parts. I am using `curl_multi_perform` and `curl_multi_add_handle` for this purpose. To give time out error after 60 seconds, if download operation get interuppted in between during download, i have used
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 60L)` and
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 30L)` curl options. Now, i want to retry 5 times after every 60 seconds to retry download (or to connect again to server) after timeout occurs. How we can do that in C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the attempt counter in the private pointer [CURLOPT_PRIVATE](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PRIVATE.html)

```
void *private;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &private);
long counter = (long)(intptr_t)private;
counter++;
if (counter < 5) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, (intptr_t)private);
  curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, curl);
}
```